# gwt logs are not generated

Tags: gwt, logging, log4j

Using gwt logs jar I am able to display logs on my console. But now I wanted to add logs in my olgs file from cient side, as we do using log4j on server side. So i reffered to http://code.google.com/p/gwt-log/wiki/GettingStarted this link but i dont see any client side logs getting generated in my log file.

Following is my gwt.xml file

```
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-DEBUG" />
<set-property name="log_DivLogger" value="DISABLED" />
<!-- In gwt-log-3.0.3 or later -->
<inherits name="com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.gwt-log-RemoteLogger" />
<set-configuration-property name="log_pattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m
   %n" />
```

Following is my web.xml file

```
<servlet>
<servlet-name>gwt-log-remote-logger-servlet</servlet-name>
<servlet-class>com.allen_sauer.gwt.log.server.RemoteLoggerServiceImpl</servlet-class>
<!--
   The `symbolMaps` parameter specifies the server directory
    containing the GWT compiler symbol maps output, which is used
     for stack trace deobfuscation
    -->
  <init-param>
       <!-- This value assumes a GWT compile with '-deploy war/WEB-INF/deploy/' -->
      <param-name>symbolMaps</param-name>
       <!--
     Modify the param-value based on your server environment. Some web servers
    use your `war` directory as the 'current working dir', while other
    vendors will do something different. You may use trial and error. Specify the
    relative path you think should work, then check the server log after forwarding
    the first client log message to the server. If the directory cannot be found,
    gwt-log will report the full path which it tried.
  -->
  <param-value>WEB-INF/deploy/detectfiles/symbolMaps/</param-value>
  </init-param>

  <!--
    Additional or alternate directories may be specified via additional parameter
  which also begin with `symbolMaps`. This may be useful if you deploy to multiple
  server environments which use different directory structures or have a different
  notion of what the 'current working directory' is.
 --> 
 <init-param>
   <param-name>symbolMaps_2</param-name>
   <param-value>WEB-INF/deploy/detectfiles/symbolMaps/</param-value>
 </init-param>

     <!-- Optionally enable CORS (http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/)
  <init-param>
     <param-name>Access-Control-Allow-Origin</param-name>
     <param-value>http://your-applications-origin</param-value>
  </init-param> 
  -->
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>gwt-log-remote-logger-servlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/com.renault.detectfiles/gwt-log</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

I have added log on clinet side as follows

```
        Log.debug("Hi this is a debug log");
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that you compile your GWT application with the additional parameter -deploy war/WEB-INF/deploy/.

Second, make sure that symbol maps exist in the directory 
`WEB-INF/deploy/detectfiles/symbolMaps/`. I observed that symbolMaps go to the directory `WEB-INF/deploy/<module-name>/symbolMaps/` when I compiled. Here, `detectfiles` does not look like your module name. Because, in the url-pattern, you have specified `com.renault.detectfiles` as the module name.

These might be the possible cause of not seeing the log.

Comment: Hi, yes my module name detectfiles. So in my url pattern i changed it to just/detectfiles/gwt-log. And symbol maps do exist in the specified directory. But still no logs are generated :(

Comment: Not sure what is the problem. You can do one thing to check the configuration at the server side is proper. Put the debug log in your servlet and check if it works fine.

Comment: debug log works fine. And its strange that there is no error or exception related to gwt logs... i am sure that somewhere i have missed out some minor thing... If you have used gwt-logs before can you paste an example over here so that i will compare and verify?

Comment: I just tried the example presented in the GettingStarted page of gwt-log. I was able to see the client side logs in the server console.

Comment: You have two entries which are either duplicate or not correct. They are symbolMaps_2 and Access-Control-Allow-Origin. Remove these params and give a try

Comment: I have removed the entry for symbol_Maps2 and that Access Control entry is already commented. But no progress :(